# To include or not?

Tags: php

My question is,
I have .php file A which loads .php file B inside a `<div>` element using jQuery `.load` function.
If I include a file with PHP functions in .php file A, do I still need to include them in .php file B if I want to use the functions there? Or is only including in .php file A enough to also use them in .php file B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs on the server. The output of the PHP is sent to the browser.

Using client-side JavaScript to combine the output of the two PHP programs isn't going to let them access each other's code.

Comment: If this is not the answer, what exactly is the question?

Comment: @HarmenBrinkman — No, of course B can't access the code of A because JavaScript includes B in A, that would be illogical.

Comment: The question is wether to include the functions file in both B and A or only in A since B is loaded in A.

Comment: Okay thanks, i'll accept this one when I can.

Comment: @HarmenBrinkman Quentin points out that B can't access A's functions. The reason for this is because B is a separate HTTP request, using jQuery, therefore it can't seeing anything inside A.

Answer (score 1):

Make a file and call that lik eehm Condig.php Include a and b in this file and include config.php in your

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function is perhaps a bit confusing. What load will do is pass the a request to a PHP function you have defined on the server. You are making a request for a resource, and getting a response. It is not actually loading those functions in for local use, as for example, an include statement in C would.

So in answer to your question, no. You will need to include the functions from A into the B file separately.